# Linear interpolation time series of data through columns

Tags: r, interpolation, na, linear-interpolation

I would like to use linear interpolation to replace NA values on a Df. On my Df columns represent a time series of daily data, so the Df in on a wide format. My data represents Days (in columns) and values of a variable, temperature, in rows. So the DF looks something like below (this is way simplified)

```
Tempdf <- data.frame ("Day1"= c(20, 22, 19, 28, NA),
"Day2" = c(NA, 24, NA, NA, 28) , "Day3"=c(23, 26, NA, NA, 29), "Day4"= c(25, 24, NA, 29, 30),"Day5"=c(24, NA, 22, 28, 29))
```

I've got a long time series of data (more than 1000 days in which some days are NA values) so I would like to interpolate those NA values based on the data within the time series. I am not sure if I need to specify a range, lets say for each NA look at the values on the same row, 3 columns before and after the NA (for example) and then interpolate that value. I need something like this as if the interpolation was made based on all columns it would look at daily values over the years so the result would be very different to the temperature data on days closer to when the NA record was missing.

So let's say temperature on Day1:Day5 was as in my example: 20, NA, 23,25,24, I would expect that NA to be around 23.

I have tried with zoo package but haven't have much luck.

```
Temp2 <- na.approx(Temp1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `t(apply(Tempdf, 1, \(x) approx(seq_along(x), x, xout = seq_along(x))$y))` will give you a matrix with the missing values interpolated. However, it will not _extrapolate_, so missing values in the first or last columns will still be missing

Answer (score 1):

You could use `approx` inside `apply`. Note that for missing values in the first or last column, this will simply copy over the adjacent value rather than trying to extrapolate a trend. For missing values in the inner columns, the value will be interpolated between adjacent non-missing columns.

```r
Tempdf |>
  apply(1, \(x) {
    if(length(which(!is.na(x))) == 1) return(rep(x[!is.na(x)], length(x)))
    approx(1:length(x), x, xout = 1:length(x), rule = 2)$y
    }) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(names(Tempdf))
#>   Day1 Day2 Day3 Day4 Day5
#> 1   20 21.5 23.0 25.0   24
#> 2   22 24.0 26.0 24.0   24
#> 3   19 21.0 23.0 22.5   22
#> 4   28 30.0 29.5 29.0   28
#> 5   28 28.0 29.0 30.0   29
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. None of the approaches are quite working. perhaps because my df has some rows in which there might be more than 2-3 NAs on consecutive days? e.g., 23,24,22,NA,NA,NA,25,NA...
Thnak you

Comment: @RGR_288 the code here works perfectly on the example you gave (as you can see). Can you please edit your question to include some data that reproduces the problem? Otherwise it's difficult to help

Comment: Sure, I've made some edits to simulate the issue. Thanks

Comment: @RGR_288 I'm still getting a complete data frame with no missing values using your new data. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: It works when I run it with the dummy data but not with my actual data. I get this error:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 't': need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Comment: @RGR_288 that means that at least one of your rows only has a single non-NA value. What would you want to happen here?

Comment: @RGR_288 I assume you would just want the whole row filled with the single non-NA value? In that case, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. If an entire row only has one non-NA value then I would prefer keeping that row as it is. Thanks!!

Comment: @RGR_288 That seems fine. So is this answer correct, or the previous version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255249/discussion-between-rgr-288-and-allan-cameron).

Comment: sorry, it keeps showing the same error

Comment: @RGR_288 are there perhaps some rows that are all `NA`?

Comment: Yes, I've just realised some rows are all NAs, sorry for not spotting before but it's a huge Df.

Comment: Yes there are some rows where all data are NAs

Answer (score 1):

`na.approx` does linear approximation so if you want the NA in

```
x <- c(20, NA, 23, 25, 24)
```

to be near 23 then you need something different.

Try this where width is the number of points minus the number of consecutive NAs to average and can optionally be omitted in which case it is set to 2 + max number of consecutive NAs.

```
library(zoo)

interp.vec <- function(x, width) {
  if (missing(width)) width <- with(rle(is.na(x)), max(lengths[values])) + 2
  ifelse(is.na(na.fill(x, c(NA, 0, NA))),
    na.fill(x, c("extend", NA, "extend")),
    rollapply(x, width, mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE, fill = NA)
  )
}

interp.vec(x, 5)
## [1] 21.50000 22.66667 23.00000 24.00000 24.00000

nms <- names(Tempdf)
Tempdf |>
  apply(1, interp.vec, width = 5) |>
  t() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(nms)
##   Day1     Day2     Day3     Day4     Day5
## 1 21.5 22.66667 23.00000 24.00000 24.00000
## 2 24.0 24.00000 24.00000 24.66667 24.00000
## 3 19.0 19.00000 20.50000 22.00000 22.00000
## 4 28.0 28.50000 28.33333 28.50000 28.50000
## 5 28.0 29.00000 29.00000 29.00000 29.33333
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This ran ok but I am still getting lots of NAs, trying to attach a screenshot

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM6RX.jpg

Comment: Can't say for sure without a reproducible example.  Maybe you used a width that is too small.  Try using the default width.

Comment: I'll try increasing the width. Can I ask for clarification about what width does? "width is the number of points minus the number of consecutive NAs to average" So let's say I've picked a width of 7. Does it mean that the function accepts up to 7 consecutive NAs from a cell with data? or that the average of an NA point is looked in the 7 surrounding cells within that row?
Thanks

Comment: It looks at width points at a time including the NAs and the non-NAs.  If you omit width, e.g. `interp.vec(x)` then  it will use a value which is 2 larger than the longest run of NA's.  If you want you can change the +2 in the function to something else to make the default even larger.